# Razer Kraken 7.1 calibration

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

I am planning on buying a headset for my pc and its either going to be the Razer Kraken Pro or the Razer Kraken 7.1. The thing is that the 7.1 is a usb headset has some software for mic calibrations and sound quality which cannot be run under linux. My question is this, is there similar software in linux to calibrate the 7.1 headset or should I go for the analog Kraken Pro? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, it's my understanding that the difference between 7.1 and stereo is made in your sound card, and that any stereo headset can be made into a virtual 7.1 headset by changing some sound options under **All Settings > Sound > Output **

change the **Mode** to **Analog Surround 7.1 Output**

However, a USB headset is preferred as it comes with its own built-in sound card (especially if your computer's sound card doesn't support anything higher than stereo).
I bought the 7.1 pro & haven't looked back. It's great.

Bottom line is, both the Kraken Pro and the Kraken 7.1 get their 7.1 audio from your sound card, and so both will have the same 7.1 audio. The Kraken 7.1 just gets more customization with the Razer software, and whatever differences there are in the specs. I don't think that Ubuntu has any of the fine-tuning that Razer's software has, but both headsets should have 7.1 surround once you set them to be that way.

Before you go off and buy one of these, take note that I'm not 100% sure that this is correct - this information is just from what I've seen whilst browsing for a new headset and personal experience with the audio options for my current pair of headphones. It'd be a good idea to go find some other sources, or wait for someone more knowledgeable to answer this question.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you understand the fact that you don't need 7.1 to experience full 3D surround sound. After all, we, humans have only two sound inputs (called ears) and there is no place to put more speakers around our head than that number.

The way human brain senses direction of the sound is more complex than disparity in sound levels between the ears. Human brain also process the phase difference between the sound sources. The sound coming from the left comes a little faster to the left ear, than to the right. The difference might seem at first glance tiny, but it is in fact quite big. The 1kHz sound produces 180° phase shift in a distance of  full phase

Comment: I believe this doesn't answer OP's question.

Comment: @GuiImamura I wanted to say, that the advertising headphones as dolby 7.1 is only a marketing trick. While technically you might get a device that *logically* presents itself as 7.1 compatible, it still has only 2 physical speakers. So you gain nothing and pay more.

Comment: Oh, I see. But what do you think about the customization software that comes in the package? I'm really curious about that too, do you think the headset is any less worthy if you can't run it? Or does it make none/little difference in your opinion? Please elaborate on it if possible :D

Comment: @GuiImamura What makes a good individual speaker is its linear response over all frequencies. Nothing more. I doubt there is anything the software can do if all you want to do is to play music. Gaming is another story - there is a lot that can be done, to make the *artificial* sound effects sound natural and 3D. And for that you would need a good sound card. I doubt the headphones alone can help you here: to render natural sound you need to know 3D properties of the rendered scene (like position of the sound relative to your character, its speed, shape of the room and the materials)